# Ждать список потоков

Tags: java, многопоточность, concurrency

Всем привет!
Подскажите, как мне решить такую задачу:
Есть класс, в котором есть поле - *List<? extends Thread>*, как функцию *waitFor()* написать, что бы при входе в нее из текущего потока, он ждал пока выполнятся все потоки из списка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

я думал такую штуку сделать:

```
 for(MyExtendedThread th: ListOfThreads){
      th.join();
 }
```

Comment: Я в Java для ПК не особо шарю, но попробуйте использовать классы `CountDownLatch` или `Future`.

Comment: как-то так:

    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(ListOfThreads.size());
    executorService.invokeAll(ListOfThreads);

Comment: @jmu, это только если мы имеем возможность запустить потоки сами. А в так вариант @voipp вполне годен.

Comment: @Nofate у меня было сомнение, что так как итерирвоание потоко-защищенное, то выбросится исключение. но вроде работает